# Can't run IIS Express in visual studio 2019

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, iis-express

When trying to run .net core project in visual studio 2019 using IIS Express the following message appears

"The ASP.NET core module is required to host ASP.NET core project and does not appear to be installed. Try repairing Visual studio to correct the problem "

Could somebody help to resolve it?

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried running repair from the Visual Studio Installer?

Also, make sure you have the `ASP.NET and web development` installed.
Visual Studio Installer->Visual Studio->Modify
[image]

Comment: yes I've tried that,and the issue appeared after repairing VS 2019

Comment: Damn that's kinda the wrong direction MS is going here lol. Have you looked at the installed workloads if there's anything related you might need?

Answer (score 1):

My solution was:

- Modify the VS Instalation and add the `ASP.NET and web development`
- Delete the .vb (hidden folder)  into  my project directory

Everything works fine after changing this.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem. Go to Asp.net and web development in installation details bracket Windows Communication Foundation  and Modify

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the Hosting Bundle for Asp Core? The error message is talking about the "IIS Asp Core Module", which is required to run core aps on IIS.

[image]

Navigate to any of the versions here https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet, then search for "Hosting Bundle".